# How do i see the durability of items in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I tried the commands they showed when you google it, i have a Mac with an apple keyboard, but i have a backup Dell keyboard, because some of the commands with an apple keyboard don't work. I'm not using any mods, besides Optifine. I play on version 1.8.4, Somehow in the past with this computer i've managed to do this, but i don't know how i did..

Answer (score 1):

Use <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> (Press the <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> key at the same time).

If that doesn't work, try <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. The <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is sometimes needed to use the actual <kbd>F3</kbd> key rather than the special function on it (like Mission Control, or brightness).